# How do I regularly deactivate inactive DAGs?

Tags: airflow

As DAGs get deleted over time they will still appear on the web UI, so I'm interested in running a process to regularly remove inactive DAGs to keep the UI as uncluttered as possible.

I notice that in `airflow.models.DagBag` there is a method called `deactivate_inactive_dags()` that appears to be this functionality, but I see it is not called anywhere in code. How is this method intended to be used?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't delete DAGs that were previously run. The only way would be to delete the respective records from the airflow database.

Comment: Yup I believe that's what the `deactivate_inactive_dags()` method already does. It doesn't quite delete from the airflow database, but it does set `dag.is_active = False` which should hide it from the UI. I'm more curious about how that function gets invoked, since there doesn't appear to be any references to it in code.